# What geographic coordinate system is this?

Tags: coordinates

I am looking at a text file with data for San Francisco, CA and the "xPos" and "yPos" fields are as an example:

(-2292840, 2017170), (-2292570, 2017170), ...

I've been stuck for hours. Does anyone know what coordinate system this is using?

Comment: Looks like a projected grid system, it's not degrees

Comment: Do you know the exact location for any of these points?

Comment: I suggest to look out for the State Plane Coordinate System that is used for your part of CA.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the coordinate system by searching through a similar shapefile. It was **USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic**. Hope this helps someone else!